# reverse backslash on string input

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to write a code for a class where i have to define a function, and the parameters come from an input(). the input is always going to be a string with numbers and letters following each other, in this form :""5 2 S 2 333 A" ". depending on the letter following the 2 numbers, i have to do use a certain function on the two previous numbers. for this i go through the string input and add each element to a list so it is easier to work with them. my issue is, that the first and last element of the last always start/end with a reverse backslash, making it impossible to int() the numbers, and i dont why and how to get rid of them. here is my code, if you know an easier way i would appreciate it but i mostly want to know where the backslashes come from...

```
def addition(a,b): 
    return a + b
def soustraction(a,b):
    return a - b
def multiplication(a,b):
    return a * b
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = input() #here comes the string input
    ma_liste = [] #the list where i want to add the elements of my string
    for i in range(0, len(c)): #checking each element of the string
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(len(c)):
                if " " in c[i:j+2]:
                    ma_liste.append(c[i:j+1])
                    break
        else:
            for j in range(i,len(c)): #check if there is a space to know where the number ends
                if c[i:j+1] == c[i-1:j+2].strip():
                    ma_liste.append(c[i:j+1])
                    break
    for e in range(len(ma_liste)): #going through the elements of my list

        if ma_liste[e].isdigit():
            int(ma_liste[e])
        if ma_liste[e].isalpha():
            if ma_liste[e] == "S":
                soustraction(int(ma_liste[e-2]),int(ma_liste[e-1]))
            if ma_liste[e] == "A":
                addition(int(ma_liste[e-2]),int(ma_liste[e-1]))
            if ma_liste[e] == "M":
                multiplication(int(ma_liste[e-2]),int(ma_liste[e-1]))
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show the code you have written as well the input and output that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do you read the numbers from a csv or text file using python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Seems like the issue here is that the end of the line `'\n'` gets appended when you read the data as it is directly. May be convert the whole `ndarray` to using `numpy.asarray` `dtype=int.` This will solve your problem. Hope it helps. :)

```
import numpy as np    
a = ['1','2','3\n']
print(a)
b = np.asarray(a,dtype=np.int)
print(b)
```

input: ['1', '2', '3\n']

output: [1 2 3]